# tool to convert avpr file to avdl file

Tags: avro

Avro's [IDL page](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html) documents that `avro-tools.jar` has an `idl` command converting an `avdl` file to an `avpr` file. Is there a way to go in the other direction, from an `avpr` file to an `avdl` file?

I was unable to find any documentation on this matter but given that the two formats appear to contain the same data with different syntax, it should be possible to convert both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a java util to create a IDL from a bunch of avro schemas, part of [spf4j-avro](http://www.spf4j.org/) for more detail [see](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-avro/src/main/java/org/spf4j/avro/schema/SchemaUtils.java#L178).  Makes schemas a lot more readable...